# Matlab xticklabel with fraction and "symbol" fontname

Tags: matlab, fonts, matlab-figure

I want to be able to use a proper fraction in the `xticklabel` context, using `'fontname',` `'symbol'`. For example :

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
set(gca, 'XTick',[pi/2]);
set(gca, 'XTicklabel',{'p/2'},'fontname','symbol');
```

I want the last `xticklabel` to the equivalent to the latex `\frac{\pi}{2}`.

What do you say?

Comment: Check here: [https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/including-symbols-in-plots-and-user-interfaces.html](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/including-symbols-in-plots-and-user-interfaces.html)

Comment: Interesting. But this will only work in unicode fonts, right?

Comment: Also, it doesn't allow for things like '30/5', for example...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text interpreter for tick labels to 'latex' and then use your latex string directly:

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
set(gca, 'XTick',[pi/2]);
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
set(gca, 'XTicklabel',{'$\frac{\pi}{2}$'});
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this is not supported in Matlab 2013, this is why (in the meanwhile) I work with the `symbol` fontname. Thanks!